# Only first row shows datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, codeigniter

Only the first row shows the datepicker and subsequent rows do not show datepicker. I have read some other references but none seem to help. Also attached image for reference. I am working on codeigniter framework.[image]Have no clue why this is happening. My view code is

```html
<?php global $USER; ?>
<style>
    .dataTables_filter
    {
        padding:10px;
    }
    .caption
    {
        margin-left:10px;
    }
    .dataTables_paginate 
    {
        float:right;
        margin-right:10px;
    }
    td,th{
        padding-left: 10px!important;
        padding-right: 10px!important;
    }
    .dashboard-stat
    {
        padding:0px!important;;
    }
    .hidden_fields {
position: absolute;
width: 400px;
height: 255px;
background: #fff;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
margin-top: 10px;

display: none;
padding-top:10px;
}

.hidden_fields  ul
{
    width:170px;
    float:left;
}
.minimize {
display: none;
}
ol, ul {
list-style: none;
}
.right_mey a
{
    color:#000;
}
</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/plugins/select2/select2_metro.css" />
<input type="hidden" id="page_name" value="requests">   
<section class="content-header">
          <h1>
          My Resignation Requests<small> <span class="">
                        </small>
          </h1>
          <ol class="breadcrumb">
            <li><a href="<?php base_url(); ?>"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">My Requests</a></li>
            <li>Resignation Requests</li>
          </ol>
    </section>

    <input type="hidden" id="page_name" value="requests">
 <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="row"> 
                        <!-- Thought Day-->
                        <div class="panel wrapper clearfix m-b-none">
                        <?php
                        $total = count($rows);
                        if($total == 0)
                        { ?>
                        <div class="panel-header"><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>exits/my_resignation_request" class="btn btn-info">Add New</a></div>
                        <?php }
                        ?>
                            <div class="">

                    <!-- BEGIN DASHBOARD STATS -->
                    <table  cellpadding="10px" border="1" style="background:none;width:75%;" RULES="ROWS" class="tab_data">
          <thead>

            <th>Employee Name</th>

            <th>Absconding Since</th>


            <th>Absconding Days</th>
            <th>Date and Time of Phone call</th>
            <th>Date of Email Sent</th>
            <th>Supervisor Comments</th>
            <th>Trigger Absconding Alert</th>




          </thead>
         <tbody>

             <?php 

                    $serial_no = 1;
                    $i = 0;
                    foreach($rows as $row){ 
                    $i++;


             ?>
                <tr>

                          <td style="width:10%">
                    <?php echo $row['firstname']; ?>
                  </td>



                    <td><div class="date" data-date="12-02-2012" data-date-format="mm-dd-yyyy" data-date-viewmode="years">
<input placeholder="Requested Last working day" class="col-md-4 form-control " id="startdt" type="text" name="requested_date" value="" required/></td>
          <td style="width:10%">
          <?php echo $row['requested_date']; ?>

                  </td>

                      <td style="width:10%">
                      <?php echo $row['last_status']; ?>

                  </td>

              <td style="width:10%">
              <?php echo $row['date_last_status']; ?>

                  </td>

              <td style="width:10%">
                <?php echo $row['agreed_date']; ?>

                  </td>



<td style="width:10%">
<?php

echo anchor('exits/raise_absconding_trigger/'.$row['userid'],"<button type='button' class='btn btn-primary'>Trigger</button>",array('rel'=>$row->id,'class'=>'edit_row'));
?>
</td>




                 </tr>
            <?php               
                } ?>

        </tbody>
        </table>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/plugins/data-tables/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/plugins/data-tables/DT_bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/plugins/select2/select2.min.js"></script>

<script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $(document).click(function(e){

                    if(($(e.target).parent().attr("class") == 'choose_field_column ') || ($(e.target).parent().hasClass('txt')))
                    {
                    } else {

                        if($(".hidden_fields").is(":visible"))
                        {
                            $(".maximize").show();
                            $(".minimize").hide();
                            $(".hidden_fields").hide();

                        }
                    }
                });
                $(".selectfunction").select2({
                    placeholder: "Select Function",
                    allowClear: true
                });
                    $(".maximize").click(function(){
                        $(this).parent().find(".hidden_fields").show();

                        $('.hidden_fields').click(function(e){
                            e.stopPropagation();
                        })
                            $(this).hide();
                            $(".minimize").show();
                    });
                    $(".minimize").click(function(){

                        $(this).parent().find(".hidden_fields").hide();
                        $('.hidden_fields').click(function(e){
                            e.stopPropagation();
                        })
                            $(this).hide();
                            $(".maximize").show();
                    });

                    function filcheck(chkval){
    if($('#'+chkval).is(':checked')){
        $("#"+chkval).removeAttr('checked');    
    }
    else
    {
        $("#"+chkval).attr ( "checked" ,"checked" );
    }

}
                $(".selectlevel").select2({
                    placeholder: "Select Level",
                    allowClear: true
                });
                $(".selectlocation").select2({
                    placeholder: "Select Location",
                    allowClear: true
                });
                $(".selectsuper").select2({
                    placeholder: "Select Supervisor",
                    allowClear: true
                });
                $(".selectyear").select2({
                    placeholder: "Select Year",
                    allowClear: true
                });


    });
</script>


<script>
/*$(document).ready(function(){
$('#reservation').daterangepicker();
})*/
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/plugins/bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>


<script>
function parseDate(str) {
var mdy = str.split('/')
return new Date(mdy[2], mdy[0]-1, mdy[1]);
}

function daydiff(first, second) {
return Math.round((second-first)/(1000*60*60*24));
}
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#startdt").datepicker({
dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
changeMonth: true,
changeYear: true,
showButtonPanel: true,
yearRange: "-90:+0",
startDate: new Date(),
autoclose: true
}).on('changeDate', function (selected) {
var minDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
$('#enddt').datepicker('setStartDate', minDate);
});
$("#enddt").datepicker({
dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
changeMonth: true,
changeYear: true,
showButtonPanel: true,
yearRange: "-90:+0"
});
$("#enddt").change(function(){
if($("#startdt").val()!='' && $("#enddt").val()!='')
{
var startdt = $("#startdt").val();
var enddt = $("#enddt").val();
$("#daysleave").val(daydiff(parseDate(startdt), parseDate(enddt)));
if($("#grievance_type").val()!='0')
{

var day_diff_today = daydiff(parseDate($("#today_dt").val()), parseDate($("#startdt").val()));

if(((parseInt($("#daysleave").val()) > parseInt($("#grievance_type option:selected").attr("data-min"))) &&  (parseInt($("#daysleave").val()) < parseInt($("#grievance_type option:selected").attr("data-max"))))&&(day_diff_today > parseInt($("#grievance_type option:selected").attr("data-approvaldays"))))
{ } else {
$("#leaveAllowedModal").modal("show");
}

}
}
})
$("#grievance_type").change(function(){
if($("#startdt").val()!='' && $("#enddt").val()!='' && $("#grievance_type").val()!='0')
{
var day_diff_today = daydiff(parseDate($("#today_dt").val()), parseDate($("#startdt").val()));

if(((parseInt($("#daysleave").val()) > parseInt($("#grievance_type option:selected").attr("data-min"))) &&  (parseInt($("#daysleave").val()) < parseInt($("#grievance_type option:selected").attr("data-max"))))&&(day_diff_today > parseInt($("#grievance_type option:selected").attr("data-approvaldays"))))
{ } else {
$("#leaveAllowedModal").modal("show");
}
}
})
$(".date-picker").datepicker();
$("#optionsRadios1").click(function(){
$("#myLTAModal").modal("show");
})
$('#leaveAllowedModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
var msg = '';
if((parseInt($("#daysleave").val()) > parseInt($("#grievance_type option:selected").attr("data-min"))) &&  (parseInt($("#daysleave").val()) < parseInt($("#grievance_type option:selected").attr("data-max"))))
{ } else {
msg = msg + "You wish you apply "+$("#daysleave").val()+" day of "+$("#grievance_type option:selected").text()+". Minimum and Maximum no. of Leaves allowed to take at a time are "+$("#grievance_type option:selected").attr("data-min")+" and "+$("#grievance_type option:selected").attr("data-max")+" respectively.";
}
var day_diff_today = daydiff(parseDate($("#today_dt").val()), parseDate($("#startdt").val()));
if((day_diff_today < parseInt($("#grievance_type option:selected").attr("data-approvaldays"))))
{
msg = msg + " No. of days of prior approval needed is  " + $("#grievance_type option:selected").attr("data-approvaldays") + " days";
}
$(".allowed_text").html(msg);

})
});


</script>
```

Comment: You using the ID selector for init the datepicker ($("#startdt").datepicker"), add a CLASS selector to all your dt fields, and change the init with something similar to $(".yourclass_startdt").datepicker...

Comment: done .. but now even the first datepicker is not working

Comment: The problem in any case is that the logical are a little more complicated. The datepicker "startdt" interacts with "enddt" on the same line. Then, the initialization and the reference to "enddt" must have a reference to the current line. Something like "$ (".yourclass_startdt").Datepicker." for initialization. And on the event "changeDate" something like "$ (this).parent ().find('.enddt')". But you will need to change several logical at your code. For my previous comment, check the rendered page with firebug or chrome console to verify the correct class name in HTML and datePicker init.